# Usage of the word "antiquarian"

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, word-usage

This question concerns the word "antiquarian".

Is it a legitimate adjective from the word "antiquity"?

I want to say something along the lines of "antiquarian context", to mean context from antiquity; is this a legitimate usage?

Comment: You might be interested in [our sister-site for English learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Not a good idea, partly because one of the meanings of ‘antiquarian’ is a person who studies antiquities. It’s difficult to advise you without know more about exactly what it is you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective from *antiquity* is [***ancient***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquity).

> **ancient** *adjective*
>   belonging to the very distant past and no longer in existence:
>      *the ancient civilizations of the Mediterranean*
>   having been in existence for a very long time:
>      *ancient forests*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ancient)

Writing of *ancient context* may be ambiguous. It is not as clear as "context from antiquity" because

- the context from antiquity does still exist — you are creating or describing it;
- the context is being described **now** and hasn't been in existence for very long.

An *ancient context* is a context **as it was in antiquity,** which can be expected not to apply now.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives are:

***archaic*** (my preferred term in this context)

adj. marked by the characteristics of an earlier period

***antediluvian***

adj. very old or out of date

***primitive***

adj. early in the history of the world or of humankind